# How to initialise a variable with index of ngFor?

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, ngfor

If I have an array pageForm of type `{id ?: number , name ?: text }`, and I want to auto initialize the id parameter with ngFor loop in HTML, what should I do?

I'm trying something like :

```html
<div *ngFor="let page of pageForm ;  let i=index; " >

 <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="page.id = i" name="id-{{i}}" >

</div>
```

Comment: Let me rephrase your question. You want the loop index to be set to id field. Is my understanding right?

Comment: exactly @Ms.Tamil

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? An `ngModel` inside an `*ngFor` doesn't seem like a pretty good idea to me as far as the performance of the App goes.

Comment: trying to sort the array using ngFor on the basis of id, so need to auto initialise the id property when click on add add user

Answer (score 2):

You can set the index value to id field in the ngFor expression as well.

```
<div *ngFor="let page of pageForm ;  let i=index; page.id=i" >

    <input type="number" name="id-{{i}}" >

</div>
```

Now the name of your input would be id-0, id-1...